# How to use field.tpl for rendered node in views3

Tags: views, entities, theming

i have set up a view (drupal 7) with a field that rendered the full node (node referenced field), and i want to get rid off the extra classes and tags wrapped around the fields.

i have copied field.tpl to my templates dir, and no matter what i name it it doesn't effect anything. I have selected that in the field settings in views. and yes, cleared the cache always.

would i name it after the content type. or the view.  i even left it at just field.tpl and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the views field template, the correct template file name would be [views-view-fields.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7).

You need to copy the template **sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php** to your current enabled theme folder. Then update the file as you need.

Rescan template files in your view theming information. The file **views-view-field.tpl.php** should be highlighted with bold. You may need to fluch the cache. It is a view template to all the fields as a row.

[image]
If you want to theme a specific field, you could use **views-view-field--[field_name].tpl.php**. It is the most specific view template.
You can check more in [Views theming](http://drupal.org/node/352970).

Comment: thank you, perfect! one thing, where is that panel you are showing above??

Comment: @user10580, If you edit your view, you will see **Advanced** in the right most panel and then find **Other > Theme: Information** under it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out what the templates should be is to use hook_preprocess_field() in your themes template file.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function THEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {

  // Check for template suggestions
  var_dump($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);

  // Add a less verbose field name class: .field-NAME
  $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class($vars['element']['#field_name']);

  // Use .field-body instead of .body
  if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'body') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'field-body';
  }

  // Remove some classes from the wrapper <div>.
  $classes_to_remove = array(
    'field',
    'field-label-' . drupal_html_class($vars['element']['#label_display']),
    'field-type-' . drupal_html_class($vars['element']['#field_type']),
    'field-name-' . drupal_html_class($vars['element']['#field_name']),
    'body',
    'clearfix',
  );
  $vars['classes_array'] = array_diff($vars['classes_array'], $classes_to_remove);
}
```

The following has the information you want...

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']
```

See: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Theres a few examples above to edit/remove classes. You can then remove any wrappers divs and extra markup from the template.